# Whats the probability of the following class that drinks coffee or tea?

Tags: probability

suppose a survey was done on 100 people, 78 people drink coffee, 40 drink tea, 10 drink neither coffee nor tea, in this class, the probability of the follows are:

1.P(coffee) = 78\100

2.P(coffee and not tea) = 0.5

3.P(tea and not coffee) = 0.12

4.P(coffee and tea) = 0.28

5.P(coffee or tea) = 0.9

6.P(not coffee and not tea) = 10\100

7.P(coffee|tea)= 28\40

8.P(tea|coffee) = 28\78

I understand how to get the first two and the sixth one, but i cant seem to figure out the others. im not seeing where the 28 comes from and 0.12. This was a practice question and these are the answer provided and no explanation was given. anyone have any idea on how to solve this would be great cause im confuse especially since it says out of 100 and 78, 40, and 10 dont add up unless some of them like coffee and tea. but its not stated.

Answer (score 1):

Given 10 People don't drink coffee or tea, then 90 people drink coffee and/or tea.

And since given 78 people drink coffee then 90-78= 12 people drink only tea and not coffee.

Since it is given 40 people drink tea, then 40-12=28 people drink tea and coffee.

From this all of the remaining probabilities can be calculated.

Answer (score 1):

From the information given, it is quite ssimple to construct a table of all the joint frequencies.  Out of one-hundred people in the sample you have:

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Tea} & \text{Coffee} & \text{Count} \\
 &  & 10 \\
\checkmark & & 12 \\
 & \checkmark & 50 \\
\checkmark & \checkmark &28 \\
\end{matrix}$$

This should assist you to see the various probabilities at issue (for a randomly selected sample participant).